# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails app where users can write quotes and other users can like them, simple as that, everything works superfine loclly but when i pushed my code in my heroku app, it is showing amd unusual error, i have completed `heroku run rake:migrate` without any error but now when i go to see quotes suppose `www.example.com/quotes/new` i get this error on console:

**error**

```
2018-05-29T17:15:29.527333+00:00 app[web.2]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528314+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528318+00:00 app[web.2]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "quotes" does not exist
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528322+00:00 app[web.2]: LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"quotes"'::regclass
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528324+00:00 app[web.2]:                                           ^
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528326+00:00 app[web.2]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528328+00:00 app[web.2]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528330+00:00 app[web.2]:                 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528332+00:00 app[web.2]:                   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528333+00:00 app[web.2]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"quotes"'::regclass
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528335+00:00 app[web.2]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528337+00:00 app[web.2]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528339+00:00 app[web.2]: ):
2018-05-29T17:15:29.528341+00:00 app[web.2]:   app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:32:in `new'
```

**20180527063820_create_quotes.rb**

```
class CreateQuotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :quotes do |t|
      t.string :author
      t.text :quote
      t.text :image_url

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**quotes_controller.rb**

```
require 'flickraw'

class QuotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quote, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]


  # GET /quotes
  # GET /quotes.json
  def index
    @quotes = Quote.all.order('created_at DESC').page params[:page]
    if @quote && @quote.image_url.blank?      
      @quote.image_url = get_flickr_image_url(@quote)
      @quote.save
    end

    #puts "using #{sort_column}"
    #puts "#{params[:key]}"


  end

  # GET /quotes/1
  # GET /quotes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /quotes/new
  def new
    @quote = current_user.quotes.build
  end

  # GET /quotes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /quotes
  # POST /quotes.json
  def create
    @quote = current_user.quotes.build(quote_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @quote.save
        format.html { redirect_to @quote, notice: 'Quote was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @quote }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @quote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /quotes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /quotes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @quote.update(quote_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @quote, notice: 'Quote was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @quote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /quotes/1
  # DELETE /quotes/1.json
  def destroy
    @quote.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to quotes_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def like
    if @quote.liked_by current_user
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  #Gives a random quote


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_quote
      @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def quote_params
      params.require(:quote).permit(:author, :quote, :image_url)
    end

    def get_flickr_image_url(quote)
      FlickRaw.api_key="f6825c919ed112e04e918353e711b02a"
      FlickRaw.shared_secret="1989755619d0054f"
      result = flickr.photos.search(:text => quote.most_significant_word, :per_page => 1, :safe_search => 1, :is_trending => true)

      #Image used in case no result is found
      biggest_url = "http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2862/10835118755_3757dab0a4_h.jpg"

      result.each do |p|
        info = flickr.photos.getInfo(:photo_id => p.id)
        sizes = flickr.photos.getSizes(:photo_id => p.id)
        photo_area = 0

        sizes.each do |size|
          calculate_area = size.width.to_f * size.height.to_f
          puts "size of #{size.label} is #{100} x #{100} : #{size.source}"
          if calculate_area > photo_area
            photo_area = calculate_area
            biggest_url = size.source
          end
        end


      end

      return biggest_url

    end  

  end
```

I have tried almost everything like resetting pg database and re migrating, but nothing helped till now.

Comment: Do you have a has_many relationship defined in the User and Quotes models?  Looks like what you want is a User `has_many :quotes` and Quotes `belongs_to :user`.  Also do you have a user_id field in the quotes table?  It looks like, from what you posted, the relationships are not set up correctly here.

Comment: yup the has_many relationship is defined in my models

Comment: can you show the migration you created that added the `user_id` field to the quotes table?

Answer (score 3):

Based on this:

```
relation "quotes" does not exist
```

It looks like you may not have done:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: if you look at my question i have already mentioned that, i have did `heroku run rake db:migrate` , it gives me this in return:
`ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"`